# Outlook VSTO recipients changed event

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I am working on an Outlook Addin written in C#. I need to implement some business logic when the recipients are changed. From my research there is not an event for this in VSTO. I tried with the **PropertyChanged** event from **MailItem**, but is firing too many times. If I pasted 2 emails in recipients then fires for every email 3 times for **TO, BCC, CC**. This doesn't help me. Is there a way to know when the user types in recipients fields or to make the property changed events not to fire so many times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a timer for that - when the event fires, reset the timer (disable/enable). Do the processing only in the timer event - this way you will process the recipients only once after a timeout.

See https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/417d026c-4486-4273-b346-94e20dad4796/propertychange-event-and-mailtitem-properties?forum=outlookdev

Comment: thank you for your answer, seems that it works on my case. I have one more questions. I show that the event fires if I clicked on the button check names or losing focus multiple times. Is there another solution to fires once the user fills the To field?

Comment: No, but why do you need a different event? Doesn't the timer trick work fro you? You can see the events firing live in OutlookSpy () - click the CurrentItem button and go to the Events tab: the event log is at the bottom of the tab.

Comment: It works and thank you for the above answer! I was wondering if the event can be fired automatically by click on the recipients fields without or before the check names.

Comment: Outlook is pretty good at firing PropertyChange event only when something changes. It can fire that event more than once or for the properties that did not change, but something still needs to change first to cause the event to fire.

Comment: Can we get the changed  Value same as of Property Name we are getting?

Comment: No, the `PropertyChange` event only passes the property name. But if you know the property name, you can retrieve that property yourself, either explicitly, or dynamically using rerflection.